# Suspend keyword as redundant with Network Request function in Spring Boot Application

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, blocking, nonblocking

I've been delving into Kotlin Coroutines and discovered that suspending functions can simplify the creation of asynchronous and non-blocking code when using Kotlin and Coroutines. In an Android application, making Network Requests as suspending functions is crucial to prevent blocking the Main Thread.

However, in a Spring Boot Application, where the concept of a Main thread isn't as prominent, there are situations where we need to wait for the Network call to return before proceeding with the next steps, which might seem somewhat 'blocking'. I even attempted to apply the suspend keyword to my client calls and launch them within Coroutines. Interestingly, Kotlin sometimes suggests that the 'suspend' keyword is redundant.

This raises the question of whether Network Requests or other I/O-bound operations can truly be considered or implemented as suspend methods in a Spring Boot context. If there is a way to implement them as suspending functions, what advantages would this bring to REST calls?

```
// suspend here is redundant...in fact, if this call takes x seconds, my API request thread will be blocked for x seconds
suspend fun makeHttpRequest(): String {
    val client = HttpClient()
    val response = client.get<String>("https://example.com/api/endpoint")
    return response
}

fun main() {
    val numberOfThreads = 4 // Adjust as needed
    val threadPool = newFixedThreadPoolContext(numberOfThreads, "CustomThreadPool")

    runBlocking {
        repeat(numberOfThreads) {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default + threadPool) {
                val result = makeHttpRequest()
                // Process the result here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `suspend` won't make blocking calls suspendable by magic. The library you use has to be compatible, and since `suspend` is a Kotlin-only feature, Java libraries will not be. So either you have to implement your own wrapper, or find a library that makes your network requests coroutine-compatible.

Comment: A suspend function that doesn’t call any other suspend functions does not benefit from the suspend keyword and that’s why it tells you it’s redundant. If you want to convert a blocking call to a suspend one, you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and if you want to convert an asynchronous call to a synchronous suspending one, use `suspendCancellableCoroutine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async/non-blocking network stack works with coroutines if and only if you use Spring **Webflux**.

Spring provides non-blocking compatibility with coroutines through Reactor (reactive streams) and Netty.

You can get more information in the following blog post section: [Webflux with coroutines API](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow#webflux-with-coroutines-api-in-kotlin).

Comment: Thank you, Could my network request become asynchronous and non-blocking when using Java CompletableFuture and Kotlin Coroutines together?

Comment: @Drex: I am not sure about CompletableFuture/suspend functions compatibility. I also depends on how Spring handles CompletableFuture return values. And, also, since the latest JDK release, there's also virtual threads to account for, that could help making code non-blocking.